# Getting "werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request" Upon Creating Form on Python Flask REST API

Tags: rest, flask, post, http-status-code-400, marshmallow

I'm learning Python Flask and following this course which is teaching me to build a RESTful API with it.

Right now, I'm trying to request information from the user (to submit) using request.form via its '/register' route, however upon testing its POST request with Postman I get *raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'email'*.

[Error as depicted in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7RxG.png)
[POST Request as shown in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUxA1.png)

I have looked at other posts with seemingly similar problems here, but either some of them also incorporate HTML (confusing!) or the solutions proposed seem to suggest .get(), which I have tried but while it prevents the 400 from occurring, it bypasses any form filling (which is not what I want).

Here is the relevant route:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
    email = request.form['email']
    test = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    if test:
        return jsonify(message='That email already exists.'), 409
    else:
        first_name = request.form['first_name']
        last_name = request.form['last_name']
        password = request.form['password']
        user = User(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, password=password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify(message="User created successfully."), 201
```

Following is all the code used so far in this file; which is called 'app.py' (also has SQLAlchemy, OS, Flask Marshmallow):

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float
import os
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow


app = Flask(__name__)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'planets.db')


db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)


@app.cli.command('db_create')
def db_create():
    db.create_all()
    print('Database created!')


@app.cli.command('db_drop')
def db_drop():
    db.drop_all()
    print('Database dropped!')


@app.cli.command('db_seed')
def db_seed():
    mercury = Planet(planet_name='Mercury',
                     planet_type='Class D',
                     home_star='Sol',
                     mass=2.258e23,
                     radius=1516,
                     distance=35.98e6)

    venus = Planet(planet_name='Venus',
                         planet_type='Class K',
                         home_star='Sol',
                         mass=4.867e24,
                         radius=3760,
                         distance=67.24e6)

    earth = Planet(planet_name='Earth',
                     planet_type='Class M',
                     home_star='Sol',
                     mass=5.972e24,
                     radius=3959,
                     distance=92.96e6)

    db.session.add(mercury)
    db.session.add(venus)
    db.session.add(earth)

    test_user = User(first_name='William',
                     last_name='Herschel',
                     email='test@test.com',
                     password='P@ssw0rd')

    db.session.add(test_user)
    db.session.commit()
    print('Database seeded!')


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


@app.route('/super_simple')
def super_simple():
    return jsonify(message='Hello from the Planetary API.'), 200


@app.route('/not_found')
def not_found():
    return jsonify(message='That resource was not found'), 404


@app.route('/parameters')
def parameters():
    name = request.args.get('name')
    age = int(request.args.get('age'))
    if age < 18:
        return jsonify(message="Sorry " + name + ", you are not old enough."), 401
    else:
        return jsonify(message="Welcome " + name + ", you are old enough!")


@app.route('/url_variables/<string:name>/<int:age>')
def url_variables(name: str, age: int):
    if age < 18:
        return jsonify(message="Sorry " + name + ", you are not old enough."), 401
    else:
        return jsonify(message="Welcome " + name + ", you are old enough!")


@app.route('/planets', methods=['GET'])
def planets():
    planets_list = Planet.query.all()
    result = planets_schema.dump(planets_list)
    return jsonify(result.data)


@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
    email = request.form['email']
    test = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    if test:
        return jsonify(message='That email already exists.'), 409
    else:
        first_name = request.form['first_name']
        last_name = request.form['last_name']
        password = request.form['password']
        user = User(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, password=password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify(message="User created successfully."), 201


# database models
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)
    email = Column(String, unique=True)
    password = Column(String)


class Planet(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'planets'
    planet_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    planet_name = Column(String)
    planet_type = Column(String)
    home_star = Column(String)
    mass = Column(Float)
    radius = Column(Float)
    distance = Column(Float)

class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')


class PlanetSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('planet_id', 'planet_name', 'planet_type', 'home_star', 'mass', 'radius', 'distance')


user_schema = UserSchema()
users_schema = UserSchema(many=True)

planet_schema = PlanetSchema()
planets_schema = PlanetSchema(many=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Any insights as to why this error is happening, and how I can fix it while still allowing the user to input the email, first_name, etc fields would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi could you please show your html for register route

Comment: Hi @CodeYard , as far as I understand, no HTML has been used here. I'm using Flask with PyCharm to create app.py (all the code shown in my question)

Comment: How are you sending the post requrst

Comment: @CodeYard I'm using Postman (https://www.postman.com/) as suggested by the course to test its routes and the requests

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of the postman request

Comment: @CodeYard I've just put screenshots of both how I did the request, and the error it showed on the post. https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7RxG.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUxA1.png respectively

Comment: Could you send the screen shot of the request body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `BadRequest` error is thrown when you try to access a object or field from the request when the client hasn't sent the field in the request.

It seems that you have made typo in you postman request. Also make sure to access it like this`request.form['']`

Comment: Given the context of the question, it's probably better to call `request.form.get('field_name')` for safety, at least to check for it.